# NSPredicate crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, nspredicate

In searchBar, I have the following code

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.filteredResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", field1, field2];
    self.filteredResults = (NSMutableArray *)[originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    originalArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return YES;
}
```

On the second time I run the predicate, the program crashes at the assignment of `self.fiteredResults` in the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:searchBar` message. If I include `[self.filteredResults removeAllObjects]` then the program crashes there, so it was removed, and still it will not function on the second time the search is performed. Does anything in this code stand out to cause the crash or should I be looking elsewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect from assigning a `BOOL` to an `NSArray`? Isn't the compiler yelling at you??

Comment: wrote the code in the question incorrect. so I proceeded to move the array assignment to the -(void) delegate method, and still get the error the second time around. Noticed the typo after wanting to alloc/init the array, but it's already doing that!

Comment: @Bicarbonate the code would not compile if you assign a BOOL to NSArray

Comment: @aug2aug It depends. Under MRC, it certainly does. You would get a warning stating that there's an "implicit conversion from integer to pointer without a cast". Trust me, I've been down this way before.

Comment: Not a doubt! Scratching my head w what I have on hand, and appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
originalArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
```

Because you're trying to set a `BOOL` to an array attribute.

---

You should make a mutable copy of the array:

```
self.filteredResults = [[originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Your assignment "self.filteredResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];" is wasteful.  You are assigning an empty array to "filteredResults", you never use it and then overwrite it two lines later.  Also, you should not be casting the result of filteredArrayUsingPredicate to NSMutableArray.  That method returns an NSArray.  If you need a mutable array, then call mutableCopy on the result.

Comment: corrected my question, made adjustments to code to get assignment to other UISearchBar delegate methods, and the bug persists

Comment: @Nicholas, the alloc init is to overwrite the resultsArray. I don't want the result to persist in that array.

Comment: I'm not sure we're communicating.  What you're doing is basically...  "self.filteredResults = 'empty array'; self.filteredResults = 'my results';"  That first assignment of the empty array is just wasted cpu cycles and a wasted memory allocation.

Comment: @NicholasHart is entirely correct, the allocation to an empty array is entirely useless

Comment: @Nicholas implies it is not necessary to empty the NSMutableArray before assigning it with results from the predicate. Check.

Comment: So what is the exception?

Comment: it's weird: `*** Webkit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate <NSUnknownException> valueForeUndefinedKey:] this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key field1`

Comment: So your predicate isn't valid for what's in the array. What is in the array? Or where else are you using 'field1'?

Comment: it's the same array as in the first time the search is run via log, and it works the first time! I guess I have to dig deeper in to this..

Answer (score 0):

The original array was being assigned correctly,

full code for working:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    NSString* documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plist.plist"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        self.arrayFromCloud = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    } 

    eventFromCloud = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary* dic in self.arrayFromCloud) {
        [eventFromCloud addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"event"]];
    }

    [eventFromCloud removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    self.filteredResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    searchBar.placeholder = @"SEARCH";

    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", @"venue name", @"starbucks"];
    self.filteredResults = [[eventFromCloud filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

    searchBar.text = nil;
    self.arrayFromCloud = nil;
    eventFromCloud = nil;
    self.filteredResults = nil;

}
```

The only way I got this code to work was by having to alloc/init the intermediary array and results array to be used the second time on the search. Originally didn't even fathom it could have been them causing the bug.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with how you wrote your predicate.  The objects in your array don't contain a "field1" property.

Comment: the darn things works the first time around, thanks for your input, but don't think that's the issue

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what's wrong.  You're telling NSPredicate to filter based on a key called "field1" and the system is telling you that it can't do that because some object in your array is not key-value compliant for "field1" (ie: that property or key does not exist on one or more objects in your array).

Comment: the code runs the first time with no problem, I run it again and it raises the error while concurrently having the same assignment to the same original array as the first time the code is run. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Just because something runs fine the first time doesn't mean there isn't a problem with your code--or the input data.  Try logging the originalArray on the line before you filter it and check the data you're trying to filter, eg: NSLog(@"originalArray: %@", originalArray);